# Using term their vs our in a marriage invitation letter

Tags: grammar

I recently happened to see an invitation letter as follows

> Mrs X and Mr Y
>
> cordially invite your esteemed presence and blessings with your family on the auspicious occasion of the marriage of **their** daughter
>
> K
>
> Grand D/o so and so
>
> with
>
> L
>
> On date at location
>
> Marriage party leaves at time.
>
> ---
>
> With Best Compliments from Friends and Relatives

Is the usage *their* correct in this context, or is *our* correct?

My understanding is if this has been called on behalf of someone else the usage of *their* is correct. But as this is called on the behalf of the parent themselves it should be *our*. Or does this have any relationship with the line *With Best Compliments from Friends and Relatives*.

Comment: Where was this? What country?

Comment: I am from India. May be you already have checked my profile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Their" fits the "Mrs. X and Mr. Y" at the beginning. I would think that if the invitation begins in the 3rd person, it would be proper to use 3rd person pronouns, as in "**They** (Mrs. X and Mr. Y) invite you to **their** daughter's wedding"...
Although some other parts of the invitation sound a little off. In any case "their" seems perfectly justified.

Comment: Cool. Thank you for the response. I will wait to see if there is any different opinion before marking this as answer.

Comment: Yes, the traditional form of a wedding invitation in the UK is in the third person. "[The bride's parents] invite you to the marriage of their daughter [name] to [bridegroom's name]".

Comment: Yes, I’d expect the third person (“their” not “our”).  Other aspects of the invitation are ridiculously improbable/wrong.

Comment: @OrbitalAussie when you say it is ridiculously wrong, can you tell me how this can be improved ?

Comment: @HariKT  My apologies, once I read this in the context of Indian English the only aspect that seems improbable or wrong is where and how the granddaughter appears (if that is who “Grand D/o” signifies). It appears to say that “K” and the granddaughter are *both* marrying “L”.

Comment: `Grand D/o so and so` : this is not a complete sentence. I just removed the words for simplicity. I can probably take a photo and post at some point of time.